# AngularJS ng-selected with if else condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options

I have a select statement using `ng-repeat` on the options and am looking for a way that if an option condition isn't met to default to a specific option.

Specifically, a drop down for country code. If an country is set, then make that the `ng-selected`, but if is set then default to the USA.  When the user selects or changes the country, the 'state' field automatically changes to that country's states/provinces.

The below code works as is, but now I need to figure out how to set the default to USA.  Can this be done with an `if/else` in the ng-selected condition?

```
  <select class="registerFields" id="user_country" ng-init="selectCountry(accountItem.user_country)" ng-change="selectCountry(accountItem.user_country);" ng-model="accountItem.user_country" ng-blur="setInfo('accountItem','user_country')">
    <option value="">Country</option>
    <option ng-selected="country.code == accountItem.user_country"
      ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.code}}">{{country.code}}: {{country.country}}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: don't use `ng-selected` just set your model and `ng-model` will take care of it

Comment: I don't understand.  If the user's country is already set to CA, then I want Canada automatically selected...but if no country is set, I want the country set to USA.  How does just setting ng-model without a condition default to USA?

Comment: Set it in your controller